# Execute an interactive shell script over apache

Tags: apache, shell, input, execute

I have a shell script which requires users input ("Please select y/n:" etc.)

I would like this to be executed through a webpage.

Any ideas on how i can do this? I have tried php shell_exec... but it just executes the commands and doesn't prompt for input.

Not sure if this is possible... But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can't answer your question which you deleted, but: [Percona has a plugin you don't have to pay for](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-pam-for-mysql/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Typically the user input would be using `HTML/Javascript`. The input is then posted to the URL ( a `PHP` script for example) which then processes the input and executes the script.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Check the script to see if there are any flags to force the script to run without user input. 
Typically you can bring up help by writing something like:

```
yourscript /h
```

or

```
yourscript --help
```

There might be a flag for that. Look for information about "force" or "prompt" in the help. If not available you could, if you are on a Linux/Unix environment, make a new script that sends the input to your other script. Unsure if that works on Windows though.

Here's a very simple example:

```
    echo y | yourscript
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is recreating the config part of the CLI tool in a form of HTML, e.g.:

```
<form method="POST" action="/foo.php">
  Please select:
      <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="1">yes
      <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="0">no
  Some other option:
      <input type="text" name"someoption">
</form>
```

Afterwards you need to create a `foo.php` that will handle the input part with HEREDOC, e.g.:

```
<?php
    $aData = some_validation_and_data_preparation_method($_POST);

    $sCmd = implode("\n", $aData);

    $sOutput = shell_exec("./some_cli_tool << EOF
{$sCmd}
EOF");

    print $sOutput;
```

Notice the lack of indentation on the actual HEREDOC (i.e. between the `EOF` markers).